# How do I start and reference my WebApplication so Watin can access it using Visual Studio UnitTesting?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, watin, vs-unit-testing-framework

I've easily setup the simple search with google example for WatiN and would like to now hook it up to my own Web Application.

I've got an MVC 3 Web Application that I'd like to test from within Visual Studio. Meaning I'd like to test my development version not a true external published website.

How do I tell the VisualStudio UnitTesting platform to startup my MVC project so its accessible to my TestMethods?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is just start the application in Cassini (Visual Studio embedded web server).
Then when it's working my Watin tests visit that app. You probably know that You can instruct web app to always use same port in Cassini? Same would work with IIS Express.

Other way is to create virtual directory under IIS and point it to your web app source folder. Then your Watin tests visit http://localhost/YourApp.

Comment: As @Peri says, Cassini is the most practical method. You can also start cassini automatically using code in your test setup.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but I guess its what I've got to do.  Thanks for confirming.